# list names of USA by php &ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to write program,which ask   user to enter  some letters or  strings and by this   string,list  these cities ,for which this string or letter is prefix
i have  following  html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","USA.php="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>entering  any city names which you like  </h3>
<form action="USA.php" method="post" >
CITY :<input type="text" name="city" value=" " onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

and also USA.php file

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$c=$_GET['city'];
$d=strlen($c);

$filename=file("UScities.txt");
$out=" ";
foreach ($filename as $line)
{

if (strtolower($c)==substr($line,0,$d)){
if($out=="")
{
$out=$line;
}
else
{
$out=$out. ' , ' . $line;
}
}
}
echo $out

?>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i run  it in firefox,it  gave me following error

> Notice: Undefined index: city in C:\xampp\htdocs\united\USA.php on line 4

but i could not understand    this error, why is city undefined index?
EDITED:

```
html code
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "USA.php?city="+str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>entering  any city names which you like  </h3>
<form action="USA.php" method="post" >
CITY :<input type="text" name="city" value=" " onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

php file

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$c=$_POST['city'];
$d=strlen($c);

$filename=file("UScities.txt");
$out=" ";
foreach ($filename as $line)
{

if (strtolower($c)==substr($line,0,$d)){
if($out=="")
{
$out=$line;
}
else
{
$out=$out. ' , ' . $line;
}
}
}
echo $out

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: who can me explain me why downvoted?

Comment: You may want to consider using [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), then you only need to worry about the php side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this one:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","USA.php?city="+str,true);
```

Ok, this is the problem. you request for hint on `USA.php` and you submit your form also in `USA.php`. Yet on requesting for list of hint, you used

`xmlhttp.open("GET","USA.php?city="+str,true);`

however you form used post method

`<form action="USA.php" method="post" >`

the problem is on `USA.php` you used post

`$c=$_POST['city'];`

I recommend you change the ff.

`$c=$_POST['city'];` => `$c=$_GET['city'];`

`<form action="USA.php" method="post" >` => `<form action="USA.php" method="get" >`

---

Last edit:
Change your condition into this my friend. and your all set!

`if (strtolower($c)==strtolower(substr($line,0,$d)))`

Comment: i have changed this line ,but code again says city undefined index

Comment: you are calling a get variable named city yet you didn't declare it. this will solve your problem with that error.

Comment: but i have indicated  city in form

Comment: also i have changed get by post

Comment: if you will change get to post, you should also change the action type of the form in post and the way you call it in php should be `$_POST['city']`.

Comment: can you post your newly edited code sir? i'm quite confused of this error. Yet i know this will be solved.

Comment: really i am confused also what is problem

Comment: i edited my answer. try my recommendation. i hope it will help

Comment: what? i copied your code and try it. and it work out just fine.

Comment: is `UScities.txt` in the same directory as the php and html file?

Comment: on USA.php replace `$c=$_GET['city'];
$d=strlen($c);` with `$c=$_GET['city'];
$d=strlen($c);
echo $c." - HERE is my keyword";`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12291/discussion-between-sephoy08-and-dato)

Answer (score 2):

You query string in the JavaScript is wrong. Change the following line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "USA.php?city="+str, true);
```